# Where do I buy gathering tools as low-level human?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Can I buy somewhere the gathering tools in Guild Wars 2 as a low level human?

I've encountered some herbs and mines wandering around, so I'd assume I'd be able to gather them somehow… but I couldn't find any vendor to provide me the tools.

The wiki [claimed](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gathering_tool) there is a vendor in Shaemoor, but apparently [he's been removed](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Horatio)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll receive copper gathering tools at level 9. If you're interested in buying some before that, Tara in the Shaemoor Garrison is a merchant, and is reachable even as a free player (as free players unlock the ability to leave starting zones at level 10.)

Most merchants sell gathering tools, but often merchants will have multiple tabs in their goods list, so they may not be immediately visible.

Answer (score 1):

They're fairly common.  There are vendors at just about every village, and a majority have gathering tools appropriate for their area.  Just look for the "merchant" tag or symbol.

If you don't see the tools when you first check with a vendor, make sure they don't have them hidden on a second page or something.  There are multiple tabs that you can view goods on for some vendors.

Worse comes to worse, check in with a trainer for a crafting profession.  They will have all tools for all levels.

If you want specific to around Shaemoor, either go back to Divinity's Reach for the profession trainers, or hop into the [garrison building](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shaemoor_Garrison) just over the bridge to the east, where you should find [Tara](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tara).

Comment: Looking at it again, yes, they were hidden in another tab. I wasn't sure if it was better to accept this answer or the other one, since this highlights the "hidden tab", but the other one highlights the "level 9"…

Comment: @Lohoris - I didn't even know about the area level lock.  Actually been a while since I played proper.  Ah well, points, and learned something.